# angular universal destroy moduleref

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

Is it possible to avoid destroying moduleRef and reuse it for next request (like working in browser)? Application spends too much time for refilling store (API-requests) so i find possibility to cache it.

Here is source code from [ngx-universal/express-engine](https://github.com/ngx-universal/express-engine/blob/master/src/express-engine.ts)

```js
function handleModuleRef(moduleRef: NgModuleRef<{}>, callback: Function, req, res) {
    const state = moduleRef.injector.get(PlatformState);
    const appRef = moduleRef.injector.get(ApplicationRef);

    appRef.tick();
    appRef.isStable
        .filter((isStable: boolean) => isStable)
        .first()
        .subscribe((stable) => {
            const bootstrap = moduleRef.instance['ngOnBootstrap'];
            bootstrap && bootstrap();

            if (!res || !res.finished) callback(null, state.renderToString());
            moduleRef.destroy(); // remove this line and avoid creating new instance of NgModuleRef every request
        });
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove that line?

Comment: It will push rendered html from the first request, also I save moduleRef after first request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging helps me to understand how it works and i was implement such code:

```
function handleModuleRef(moduleRef: NgModuleRef<{}>, callback: Function, req, res) {
    const state = moduleRef.injector.get(PlatformState);
    const appRef = moduleRef.injector.get(ApplicationRef);
    const router = appRef.components[0].instance.router;
    const zone = appRef.components[0].instance.zone;
    zone.run(() => {
        router.navigateByUrl(req.originalUrl);
    });
    appRef.isStable
        .filter((isStable: boolean) => isStable)
        .first()
        .subscribe((stable) => {
            const bootstrap = moduleRef.instance['ngOnBootstrap'];
            bootstrap && bootstrap();

            if (!res || !res.finished) callback(null, state.renderToString());
        });
}
```

*We need to inject Router and NgZone in main component that was bootstrapped*

When we come into "handleModuleRef" we need to destabilize (isStable=false) application for start "changeDetector" by pushing new navigation url to router. But if you know "isStable" is a property of zone (one per application) and trick is to call "router.navigateByUrl" inside "zone.run(...)" to destabilize zone. 
1) Application handles new route
2) zone destabilizes itself
3) wait until it will be stable (no one tasks inside zone)
4) render
5) profit!

**Results:**

- rendering accelerates in 2-3-4 times by caching all application in memory and avoiding bootstrap for each request
- memory leaks are possible (app started in docker and it will restart if will fall accidentally)
- continuous state of application